# Assigning number value to a variable in VBA

Tags: ms-access, variables, syntax, vba

I need to assign a number value to a variable in VBA.

I did this:

```
var num as integer
num=1
```

but when I put a breakpoint at `num=1` and see the value of `num` it's showing 0 (zero).

Please help.

Answer (score 8):

The breakpoint stops on the current instruction without executing it. Try stepping over it and see if the value changes.